# (x86 Assembly) Buffer size is specified 1 byte for stdin, but why buffering more than 1 byte if provided on stdin?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am defining `buff` in `.bss` section as just 1 byte buffer for taking one character as input and converting it to uppercase, and then showing it on stdout. But when I provide more than 1 character in input (a string), it still converts the whole string to uppercase! How can it buffer more than one byte if I have specified to buffer a single one. Is there another buffer after stdin which keeps feeding my buffer 1 byte a time?

My code:

```
SECTION     .bss
buff        resb        1
SECTION     .data
SECTION     .text
global      _start
_start:
        NOP                             
read:           
        MOV     EAX, 3              ; Read syscall
        MOV     EBX, 0              ; Standard input  
        MOV     ECX, buff           ; Specify the buffer for stdin
        MOV     EDX, 1              ; 1 char at a time
        INT     0x80                ; Interrupt for the syscal
        CMP     EAX, 0              ; Look at the return of read syscall, if 
                                    ; unsuccessfull, exit
        JE      exit                ; If the input was 0, jump to exit
        CMP     byte [buff], 0x61   ; Test for lowercase, lowercase are above
                                    ; 0x61 - 'a'
        JB      write               ; Jump if below 'a' ASCII 0x61
        CMP     byte [buff], 0x7A   ; Test for above 'z'- ASCII 0x7A
        JA      write               ; Jump to write if input above 'z' 
        SUB     byte [buff], 0x20   ; A lowercase input finally, convert it to
                                    ;uppercase by subtracting 0x20h
write:          
        MOV     EAX, 4          ; Write syscall
        MOV     EBX, 1          ; Write on stdout
        MOV     ECX, buff       ; take from this buffer
        MOV     EDX, 1          ; 1 charcter at a time
        INT     0x80            ; Interrupt for the syscall
        JMP     read            ; Jump for reading again
exit:           
        MOV     EAX, 1          ; Exit syscall
        MOV     EBX, 0          ; Errorcode in EBX
        INT     0x80            ; Interrupt for exit syscall
```

Comment: Sounds like you're overwriting other bytes following `buff`. The `.bss` section may well contain some padding to make it a multiple of N bytes, so for small quantities of data you could get away with this. But you obviously shouldn't access data that you haven't allocated.

Comment: I'm confused, don't you have a loop in your code?

Comment: Yes, the OS has an additional buffer which in case of terminal is normally set up to store a full line (notice you won't get the first character converted until you press enter).

Comment: @Michael I don't think giving more than 1 char is overwriting buff, if I was, then giving, say 'what' in stdin would print 't' only, not 'WHAT'.

Comment: `jmp read` maybe you enter 5 chars at once, but each loop, you read only one. so after entering your string, you program loops through ALL of the chars entered. each int 0x80 call will return you one byte, and keep the others buffered

Comment: @Tommylee2k Yeah, that is what is happening. How can I prevent it?I need only that buffer size that I specify, not all of the stdin buffer.

Comment: The terminal in Linux works the way ancient teletypes (TTY) worked back in the 1970s.  Input is line-buffered, nothing happens until you press the Enter key.  So you'll type a bunch, press Enter and then your code starts running, converting one char at a time.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: It's unclear what you want. If you simply don't want to process the other characters, just don't loop back. As simple as that. Otherwise, either discard them or change your terminal mode.